# Find unique numbers from series without breaking order

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I'm new to stackOverflow. Please assist me if its repeative post. 
I'm C++/STL developer and looking for:

finding unique numbers from series on integer number wihtout changing its order. e.g: i/p: 10,4,3,6,1,0,4,4,4,10,5,9,0,6,15,.... o/p(expected result): 10,4,3,6,1,0,5,9,15,....

Constraint: - time complexity should not be worst(N^2). Need to solve it in less time. - memory is adequate. - appricieate, if you can explain about STL containers or algorithm I must use to resolve this problem.

I tried using unorder_set but it break the ordering so bit confused.

Comment: Can you show what algorithms you have tried?

Comment: O(N) memory: copy, sort, unique

Comment: question best suited for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The naive approach is `O(n²)`, (insert only when not already present).

Comment: I'm not looking for naive approach.

Comment: @caveman - I just used unorder_set container. No algo. I want to prepare it.

Comment: @David - ur way is correct but understand my question correctly. I mentioned that it shud not break ordering. Check e.g provided.

Comment: @VGG: you only need to handle the order as additional information, you can store `pair<int,int>` (value, index), run sort on value, then unique, then sort on index and you retain the original order. The comment above was assuming that you did not want to break the order of the original container, and assuming that breaking the order of a copy would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::unordered_map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
 std::unordered_map<int, int> mynums;
 std::vector<int> myvect = {10,4,3,6,1,0,4,4,4,10,5,9,0,6,15};
 for (auto myelem: myvect) {
   mynums[myelem]++;
 }
 for (auto myelem: mynums) {
   if (myelem.second > 1) {
     std::cout << "Value "<<myelem.first << " " << myelem.second << " times" <<std::endl;
   }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

The approach prints only repetetive numbers and should have amortized O(n) complexity.

The code that would be in your interest would then look as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
 std::unordered_map<int, int> mynums;
 std::vector<int> myvect = {10,4,3,6,1,0,4,4,4,10,5,9,0,6,15};
 for (auto myelem: myvect) {
   if (mynums[myelem] == 0) {
      std::cout << myelem << ",";
   }
   mynums[myelem]++;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: thnx. I think we can club both the loop. 
1. can linerly tranverse vector and one loop 
2. call unorder_set::find(myelem). if no. found then ignore
3. else store myelem in unordered_set
This will do the job in O(nlogn) complexity but within one loop. In ur logic it will traverse loop twice though complexity in ur case is looks better O(n).
Wat u say?

Comment: Yes it will give amortized O(n) as the insertion and access to unordered_map is amortized O(1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::unique`, and then add `resize` to resize your `vector` (or another container):

```
auto it = myvector.begin();
it = unique (myvector.begin(), myvector.end());                                                                
myvector.resize(distance(myvector.begin(),it) );
```

Comment: This only works if the values are sorted, which is not the case

Comment: @VVG - I doubt that it will maintain the order. Can u please explain how it will work. Even not sure about time complexity of unique and resize and distance. Please mention that as well.

Comment: @VGG: Time complexities: sort: O(n log n); unique: O(n); distance: O(1); resize: O(n)... but then again, this is something you should be able to research yourself, like in ... google

Answer (score 0):

The naive approach in `O(n²)`:

```
std::vector<int> find_unique_numbers(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    std::vector<int> res;

    for (auto e : v) {
        if (std::find(res.begin(), res.end(), e) == res.end()) {
            res.push_back(e);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/sZegEQ)